# Google Sheets Api Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

```
static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
static string ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart";
public String spreadsheetId;
SheetsService service;

public GoogleHandler(String id)
{
    spreadsheetId = id;
    UserCredential credential;
    using (var stream =
            new FileStream(@"bin\client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
            System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    }

    service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });
}
```

This is my code for Google Sheets API. I have the `static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };` which were solutions I found for this problem, however that did not fix my problem. I have already deleted my .credentials folder and it does not prompt me to login.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: The title is the problem. Request had insufficient authentication scopes

[403] error

Comment: Have you done the first Step in this quickstart guide? https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: Yes, I completely restarted and went through all of the steps.

Answer (score 2):

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None
            //new FileDataStore(credPath, true)
            ).Result;
```

I commented out that line and it fixed everything!