# Insufficient authentication scopes in relation to Syntax "Update"

Tags: c#, wpf, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

Goal:
Use Google Sheet API by using the syntax code "spreadsheets.values.update" in order to update the current cell.

Problem:
I have used the code that is provded by Google Sheet's tutorial (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) and it doesn't work.

I retrieve a error message saying:

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'Google.GoogleApiException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError

Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [403]

Errors [

    Message[Request had insufficient authentication scopes.] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]

]"
```

Info:
*I was enable to use Oath 2.0 authenfication in relation to syntax code "spreadsheets.values.get" (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) and it works perfectly.
*The same code of Oath 2.0 that is used in "spreadsheets.values.get" works well.
*It is the same authenfication when I use for "get" and "update". It works for "get" but not for "update".

Thank you!

[image]

```
private void btn_test6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets};
    string ApplicationName = "SheetUpdate"; //update this!


    UserCredential credential;

    using (var stream =
        new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
    }


    SheetsService sheetsService = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Google-SheetsSample/0.1",
    });

    // The ID of the spreadsheet to update.
    string spreadsheetId = "";  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // The A1 notation of the values to update.
    string range = "datadata!A1:A6";  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // How the input data should be interpreted.
    SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum valueInputOption = (SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum)0;  // TODO: Update placeholder value.



    IList<object> my = new List<object>();
    my.Add("a");
    my.Add("a");
    my.Add("a");
    my.Add("a");
    my.Add("a");
    my.Add("a");

    IList<IList<object>> my2 = new List<IList<object>>();
    my2.Add(my);



    // TODO: Assign values to desired properties of `requestBody`. All existing
    // properties will be replaced:
    Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.ValueRange requestBody = new Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.ValueRange();
    requestBody.Values = my2;






    SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest request = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(requestBody, spreadsheetId, range);
    request.ValueInputOption = valueInputOption;

    // To execute asynchronously in an async method, replace `request.Execute()` as shown:
    Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.UpdateValuesResponse response = request.Execute();
    // Data.UpdateValuesResponse response = await request.ExecuteAsync();

    // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your asking, nor what your problem exactly is. You seem to have answered your own question (?), is this still a problem for you?

Comment: Yes, this is still a problem. The problem the authenfication problem

Comment: The authenfication problem don't work in relation to "update" but when I use the same authenfication for retrieving "get" data from the sheet, it works. I don't know what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Update requires following Authorization scopes

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`

see [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Try modifying scopes in array and update application/project's rights in google consoles' [OAuth consent screen](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent) and adding these scopes there too.

Answer (score 1):

replace this line:

```
static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets.ReadOnly };
```

with this:

```
static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
```

and if you did not pass, delete (token.json) folder and try again

Answer (score 0):

Remove new FileDataStore

```
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None //,
                                   //new FileDataStore(credPath, true)
            ).Result;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47587237/google-sheets-api-request-had-insufficient-authentication-scopes?rq=1